# Can you copy an array formula down without having to hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter?

Tags: arrays, excel

I tried a fix like under "[excel array formula: not have to 'ctrl-shift-enter'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526573/excel-array-formula-not-have-to-ctrl-shift-enter)" Here's my formula:

```
=(0*0)+SUM(IF(A10=Bundle!$B$2:$B$58233,1/(COUNTIFS(Bundle!$B$2:$B$58233,A10,Bundle!$N$2:$N$58233,Bundle!$N$2:$N$58233)),0))
```

The "before the fix" formula works, but there are a lot of rows, and it would take a long time to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> all 2624 times. I added the code as suggested and the `0*0` like above, but it didn't work.  Do I have to do something to activate the code?

This and several other posts online suggest that array formulas will just fill-down, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You should be able to just drag the formula down, like any other.  What happens when you do so?  Also, where was it suggested to do (0*0)? I'm not saying it's incorrect, only that it looks like you're getting some tips from somewhere and I'm just curious as to where.  (I.e. to understand what you mean "before the fix").  Also, does [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526573/excel-array-formula-not-have-to-ctrl-shift-enter?rq=1) help?

Comment: You are think of a Google-Docs sheet that autopopulates cells below the cell where an array-type function is input.

Comment: The question you refer to is where I got the (0*0).  It has this code to go with it:  Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Target
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If InStr(1, Target.Formula, "(0*0)+", vbTextCompare) And _
            Target.HasArray = False Then
            Target.FormulaArray = Target.Formula
        End If
    End If
Next cell

End Sub

Comment: You might also want to look into an alternate solution that doesn't fill 2625 rows with an array formula that references 58232 rows of data.

Comment: This is the only solution I've found other than manually counting each location (Bundle Column N) within each customer account (Bundle Column B).  It's a $10 mil question for my client, so I'd like to figure it out.  I'm going to try pulling just the columns I need out and then subtotaling. It might work without the other columns present (it didn't before).

Comment: The lack of any redacted sample data makes it very difficult to offer suggestions toward improving efficiency. It seems that you are looking for some sort of two column COUNTUNIQUE type of function.

Comment: Sorry I haven't gotten back to this.  The array formula I was using was working, but taking far too long to calculate (would have taken weeks).  Thus it appeared to be doing nothing.  I realized I could break my data down into chunks (thanks Jeeped!), and use the formula on each piece (reduced the number of referenced cells).  It still took quite some time for each chunk to calculate, but then I could change the formulas to their computed values and move on.

Answer (score 2):

If the array formula is in cell B2, and you want to copy and paste the formula to cells B3:B10, you can **ONLY** paste the formulas to cells **B3:B10**. You can't include cell **B2** when you paste the formulas or you will get a "you cannot change part of an array" error message.

Comment: Funny, I've filled and copied down array formulas for years. It is only when it is initially put into more than a single cell that I have trouble.